# Is there any information on Zordon of Eltar?

Tags: history-of, power-rangers, zordon

The American version of *Kyōryū Sentai Zyuranger,* or the **Might Morphin Power Rangers,** introduces their mentor Zordon as a "Space Wizard" who was trapped in a dimensional tube. Im the Japanese original, the team's mentor was an ageless mysterious Sage named Barza, who was in human form with them. MMPR canon states that Zordon was fighting Rita Repulsa---- and her lord the Dark Emperor Zedd--- for years, and that he was "trapped" in the tube by Rita's trickery, which put him out of sync with this dimension. Despite this, Zordon still had a limited, but potenet amount of power in this reality, and with his guidance, his previous team of young heroes defeated Rita while Zedd fled to recharge his powers. Zordon would then set up a command center on earth to protect the planet from other outbreaks of evil, while Rita remained imprisoned for 10,000 years.

**Mighty Morphin Power Rangers: The Movie** elaborated more, stating Zordon was a "legendary inter-dimensional being" who came to earth and established a base for fighting a "never ending battle against evil" in its opening narration. A conversation with Ivan Ooze (the big bad of that film), stated that Zordon came from the planet [or dimension, or possibly tribe] of "Eltar". Later in the series [ **Power Rangers in Space** ], Zordon's incredible power was implied, as a season-long search went on for him, and his death would trigger a "Z-wave" which was powerful enough to transform or obliterate the major antagonists from the previous 6 seasons. But little other information is given on the character.

Considering that the "Zords" seem to be named after or partially inspired by Zordon, it implies that he is pretty important.

So is there any information on what Zordon's backstory in *this* franchise [not the alternate dimension 2017 film] might be?

I'm aware there are a few comic book series, but I'm not super familiar with them, so information from those maybe useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the comic series, but I have watched a majority of the material which featured Zordon from the various series.

Overall, while there may be more background details in the original series bibles or development notes, there is no further information in officially published materials.

The most likely sources for any additional information would be the comic series, though I do not know if it is likely to contain any more details, or interviews with the writers and/or producers.  There are often Q&A sessions at conventions as well, but those can be hit-or-miss on the viability of the information given, especially for properties that still have new material being produced.

There IS a lot more information about Zordon's history in the 2017 movie, but you specifically excluded that.